# Is that possible to take an item from the struct array and then append to different array in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to get an amount from the firstArray, then append to secondArray. I got this error: 
"Cannot invoke initializer for type 'ForEach<_, _, _>' with an argument list of type '([Number], @escaping (Double) -> ())'"

```
struct Number: Identifiable {
let id = UUID()
let amount: Double
}

struct ContentView: View {

@State var firstArray = [Number(amount: 10),Number(amount: 30),Number(amount: 50)]
@State var secondArray = [Double]()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(firstArray) { row in
            secondArray.append(row.amount)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should probably make a custom initialized for the `Number` struct

Comment: Don't manipulate the view state while rendering the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything marked with `@State` is a source of truth. If your second array is always reliant on your first array, it should not be a state variable (it could be a computed property using map, as seen below).

If you are sure that you want to have two `@State` variables, you should initialize it separately, not changing it in the view.

```swift
///MARK: - computed property
struct Number: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let amount: Double
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var firstArray = [Number(amount: 10),Number(amount: 30),Number(amount: 50)]
    var secondArray: [Double] = {
        return firstArray.map { $0.amount }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
//            ForEach(firstArray) { row in
//                secondArray.append(row.amount)
//            }
        }
    }
}

struct Number: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let amount: Double
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var firstArray = [Number(amount: 10),Number(amount: 30),Number(amount: 50)]
    var secondArray = firstArray.map { $0.amount }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
//            ForEach(firstArray) { row in
//                secondArray.append(row.amount)
//            }
        }
    }
}

struct Number: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let amount: Double
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var firstArray = [Number(amount: 10),Number(amount: 30),Number(amount: 50)]
    @State var secondArray = firstArray.map { $0.amount }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
//            ForEach(firstArray) { row in
//                secondArray.append(row.amount)
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

I strongly recommend the first option, as it will always have the `amount`s of everything in the second array.